# Clarifying the definition of big-oh

Tags: asymptotics

I am a computer science student and I am familiar with big-oh notation in algorithm analysis books. But the book I am working for mathematical analysis is using somewhat different asymptotics definitions to analyze vanishing rate of the error term of the Taylor series. Here is the definition:

**Defn:** We say $f(t)$ **vanishes at least to order p** (at the origin), and write $f(t) = O(p)$, if there are positive constants $\delta$ and $C$ for which

$$\mid f(t) \mid \leq C \mid t \mid^p$$
when $\mid t \mid \lt p$.

I don't understand this "vanishes at least to order p" part. Later, the book says; **if $f(t)$ vanishes to at least to order p, there is no reason to think $f(t)$ vanishes to higher order than p.**

If it can not vanish to order higher than p, doesn't that mean it vanishes at most to order p, not at least? Can you clarify this definition and explain the last bold-faced part? **Can a function $f(t) = O(p)$ vanish to order greater than p?**

Comment: "*there is no reason to think that it vanishes to higher order than $p$*" but it still *could*.  This is just saying that there are examples of $f$ for both scenarios.  There are some $f$ which are $f(t)=O(p)$ which do not vanish to any higher orders than $p$, and there are other $f$ which are also $f(t)=O(p)$ which do vanish to at least one higher order than $p$.

Comment: if we wanted to explore how a polynomial grows as the variable(s) grow(s) we can relate it to the highest degree  example:  $$x^3+2x^2+8x+1$$ we can show that after certain values of x the lower exponents don't really add much compared to the $x^3$. for x> 0,  8x>1  for x>4 , $2x^2 >8x$ for x>2 $x^3>2x^2$ so by x=5 the greatest change of the value comes from that $x^3$ term.

Comment: I think the given definition of big-oh in the book and above is not related to growth rates I know from algorithms but related to vanishing rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|f(t)|\leq C|t|^p$, it *might* also be the case that $|f(t)|\leq D|t|^{p+1}$, because $|t|^{p+1}\leq |t|^p$ near $t=0$. But it *must* be the case that $|f(t)|\leq C|t|^k$ for $k<p$ because then $|t|^p\leq |t|^k$ near $t=0$. The statement "$f(t)$ is $O(p)$" does not say $p$ is the *sharpest* bound you can get, but it does imply a minimal degree of sharpness. As a result, it is best to read the statement as guaranteeing a minimal degree of vanishing, not specifying the best possible bound. That is why your book tells you to call this property vanishing to "at least" order $p$: they don't want you to make the mistake of thinking the order is exactly $p$.

Just look at a concrete example. Say you know $|f|$ is bounded by a constant times $t^2$. This means $|f|$ is also bounded by a constant times $|t|$, because $t^2<|t|$ for small nonzero $t$. But you don't know whether you can do better and bound $|f|$ by a higher-order power.

The general point is that if $a<b$ and you are interested in some $c<b$, it *might* be true that $a<c$, but it certainly doesn't have to be true.

Comment: So it is *sure* to vanish to order p and less, and it *might* vanish to order greater than p.

Comment: @meguli precisely.

Comment: @meguli: yes, that's right.

Comment: I think the trouble is that you were reading "there is *no reason to think it vanishes* to higher order" as "there is *reason to think it doesn't vanish* to higher order." That is a scope error. The book meant is that if *all* you know is that a function is $O(p)$, that, in itself, is not a reason for thinking it vanishes to higher order. But you might, by some deeper analysis, find an *independent* reason to conclude it *does* in fact vanish to higher order.